# How to combine cloth simulation with particles

Tags: particles, cloth-simulation

Is there a way to combine cloth simulation with particle system?

I want to create many cloth pieces flying around some force field etc? I tried for couple of hours but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's possible to do, what kind of cloth simulation and how complex of a particle system? Just simple planes, or something else? Do you have some reference of what you want to do?